# Dataquest , Question about updating dictionary?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain the red line. Why would we program `content_ratings[bilal]` I dont really understand the logic behind that. I know we are updating the empty dictionary but why would we program what we programed?

[image]

```
ratings = ["4+","4+","4+","9+","12+","12+","17+","17+"]
content_ratings = {}

for bilal in ratings:
    if bilal in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[bilal] += 1
    else:
        content_ratings[bilal] = 1
print(content_ratings)
```

Comment: "why would we program what we programed?" Can you clarify please?

Comment: I don't get the fact why we would say content_ratings[bilal] to update the value of the empty dic(content_ratings={}) that was created before the for loop?

Comment: Another question like what value does content_ratings[bilal]  Talking about the same line the code can also be written like this:                                  
content_ratings[bilal]= content_ratings[bilal]+1.

Comment: Oh so you want an explanation on how the code in the image works?

Comment: I understand the output of  the code but i just don't know what 'content_ratings[bilal]' represent and why we would have to use that to update original dic that was created before the for loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary `content_ratings` calculates number of times a given rating appears.

So `if bilal in content_ratings` checks that if the key already exists.

If there is no item till now which is the same as the value `bilal` is currently having, the count is set to one.

However if there is already an item, then we need to increase its count by one since we got one more.

---

There is a much simple and faster way to do the above same thing.

```
from collections import Counter
ratings = ["4+","4+","4+","9+","12+","12+","17+","17+"]
content_ratings = Counter(ratings)
```

Comment: but what is the key?

Comment: The variable that stores the key in the code you provided is `bilal`, the for loop iterates the key over the values in the list `ratings`, so the key takes the values `"4+"`, `"4+"`, `"4+"`, `"9+"` .. and so on

Comment: In your code, `content_ratings[bilal]` represents the number of times the value stored by bilal currently has been counted previously by your code.

If its the first time, you add it by `content_ratings[bilal] = 1`, otherwise you do `content_rating[bilal] = content_rating[bilal] + 1` which is the same as `content_rating[bilal] += 1`

Comment: that makes alot of sense and I am getting the hang of it, but then if i type print(content_ratings[bilal]) outside the loop why doesnt it access the keys you are talking about?

Comment: `bilal` is just a temporary variable used by the `for` loop, so outside the loop it would lose its meaning. You can try printing it inside like this after the `if-else` using `print(bilal, content_ratings[bilal])` to see how the value changes

Comment: okay that makes a lot of sense now thank you. I appreciate it!

Comment: Your welcome. If the answer helped you can turn it accepted I guess :lol

Comment: for sure can you tell me how I can do that I am new to Stack Overflow and also after i trun it in can I still view your comments?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work If an answer helps you, you can accept it like that.